# Aligning nested div elements with inline-block

Tags: html, css

I am attempted to have set two div elements within another div to be alongside each other.

The css I currently have sets the two divs to be `display: inline-block;` with the `width` elements of the two divs adding up to 100%, thereby filling the whole parent , however this causes the two divs to stack, rather than appear next to each other.

Applying a `float: left` to one of the  elements will cause them to appear alongside each other, as will changing the sum of the `width` to be <100% (i.e. 39% and 60%)

My question is what causes the divs to stack, and need to be floated? Is there some buffer I can't see that prevents you from having two divs that add up to 100% inside another one?

Below is an example of the problem.
https://jsfiddle.net/q1g9z1o4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline elements have an empty space between them (like words in text). Removing all white-space from the fiddle solves this.

`<div id="div1"><div id="inner1"></div><div id="inner2"></div></div>`

[This css tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) has several solutions to your problem:

- Remove the spaces
- Negative margin
- Skip the closing tag
- Set the font size to zero
- Use float instead
- Use flexbox instead

https://jsfiddle.net/ts0u828x/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
display: inline-block;
```

with

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1g9z1o4/1/)